# Creating a Java Swing pop up window to request for details

Tags: java, swing, validation

i am beginning java swing programming and i was wondering how to do the following:

i want, as the program starts, that a pop up window will appear and request the user for something simple, his full name, and then assign it to a variable, String for instance.

i want that the user won't be able to use the program until he puts his full name.

i will do the checking to verify that what he wrote is his name(doesn't consist numbers or special letters, has a length not smaller than 3 etc..) - but my main goal is just creating that pop up window.

thank you in advance for your assistance and for helping me at my java swing learning curve.

Comment: JOptionPane dialogs are probably what you want. Remember, as a programmer, Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String input = JOptionPane.ShowInputDialog("Enter your full name");` to read and assign it to a variable called `input`.

Full name might consists of several names and spaces.
Then use String methods like substring(), trim() and indexOf() to make sure you at least get first and lastname.

Visit https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_ref_string.asp for more String methods.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you give please an example with some basic code? what i want to see is how when the program starts, first thing a pop up window follows and asks the user to submit his name, and then other stuff happening in the gui. i want to make it that the user won't be able to use the program until he submits his name. thank you very much!

Comment: That first line I provided you with starts the program with a window opening, asking for full name. 

You have to add if-else statements to make sure the user meets the requirements,

For example `if(input.lenght() < 20){JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null, "You need at least 20 characters")}` // If input is less than 20 characters a new window opens and sends a message.